# How necessary is using the perfect past in the given sentences?

Tags: past-perfect

> I **had** bought myself a phone, and then one day, it got stolen.
>
> I bought myself a phone, and then one day, it got stolen.

Is the meaning of first clearer than the second?
Is there a difference in both the sentences' meaning?
Is using the past perfect necessary here?

Comment: "I bought me a phone" sounds like Pirate English. Something like what [Tia Dalma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tia_Dalma) might say in Pirates of the Caribbean.

Comment: There are already numerous questions/answers discussing this very topic. Furthermore, in both of your sentences you're not the object of the verb, hence you ought to use “myself” in lieu of “me”.

Comment: "I bought a phone and then one day it was stolen."

Comment: @VarunKN - Or if not pirates, cowboys.

Answer (score 1):

Past perfect is not strictly necessary here.  Especially since you have extra words (*and then one day*) indicating the relation of time between the two events.

In situations like this *had* can serve to emphasize the "pastness" of an event.

Past perfect is not optional is when it is not referring to an action at a specific time.  The following is excerpted from [here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html):

> Compare the examples below. Here Past Perfect is referring to a lack of experience rather than an action at a specific time. For this reason, Simple Past cannot be used.
>
> Examples:
>
> She never saw a bear before she moved to Alaska.  (Not Correct)
>
> She had never seen a bear before she moved to Alaska.  (Correct)

Continuing to excerpt from that same source - note that past perfect can also express that "something started in the past and continued up until another action in the past."

Some sentences (like the second) will sound a bit "off" if you don't use past perfect here, and you should generally use past perfect when you mean this to be the most clear.

> With Non-Continuous Verbs and some non-continuous uses of Mixed Verbs, we use the Past Perfect to show that something started in the past and continued up until another action in the past.
>
> Examples:
>
> We had had that car for ten years before it broke down.
>
> By the time Alex finished his studies, he had been in London for over eight years.
>
> They felt bad about selling the house because they had owned it for more than forty years.
>
> Although the above use of Past Perfect is normally limited to Non-Continuous Verbs and non-continuous uses of Mixed Verbs, the words "live," "work," "teach," and "study" are sometimes used in this way even though they are NOT Non-Continuous Verbs.

Comment: Your bear and car examples are misleading. There's nothing 'Not Correct' about *She never saw a bear before she moved to Alaska* or *We had that car for ten years before it broke down*, because there's nothing in those sentences establishing the time of the move or of the breakdown as your Reference Time. These, however, **would** have very different meanings, which probably **are** incorrect: *She never saw a bear **when** she moved to Alaska*, *We had that car for ten years **when** it broke down*.

Comment: @StoneyB, do you have some time on your hands?
I would like to be taught some stuff in the chat room.

Comment: Not at present. Maybe next week.

Comment: @StoneyB, Okay. :P